# Cannot trigger alt store with alt action (Flux)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, flux

I'm developing a flux frontend program with [goatslacker/alt](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt). And I have problem triggering store to update with action. The listener is not functioning as I expected it to be.

The code I'm working on is quite complicated now. I'll try to simplify my problem into the following code. I expect it to log "Hello World! msg: Some message" in the end. Apparently, the listener `hello()` doesn't even run.

This is the main javascript (ES6) file to be run:

```js
import alt from './alt';

class DummyActionsProto {

  sayHello(msg) {
    console.log("sayHello", msg);
    return {msg}
  }

}
var DummyActions = alt.createActions(DummyActionsProto);

class DummyStoreProto {

  constructor() {
    this.bindListeners({
      hello: DummyActions.sayHello,
    });

    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  hello(msg) {
    console.log("Hello World! msg: "+msg);
  }

}
var DummyStore = alt.createStore(DummyStoreProto, 'DummyStore');

// trigger the action
DummyActions.sayHello("Some message");
```

The ordinary `alt.js` code it includes:

```js
import Alt from 'alt';
module.exports = new Alt();
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short the store can only catch the action if you add `this.dispatch()` in the action method. So instead of return anything in that method, you should run `this.dispatch()` (with or without parameter). The listener will be run with the parameters of `this.dispatch()`.

The corrected version:

```js
import alt from './alt';

class DummyActionsProto {

  sayHello(msg) {
    console.log("sayHello", msg);
    this.dispatch(msg); // **instead of return, you should do this**
  }

}
var DummyActions = alt.createActions(DummyActionsProto);

class DummyStoreProto {

  constructor() {
    this.bindListeners({
      hello: DummyActions.sayHello,
    });

    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  hello(msg) {
    console.log("Hello World! msg: "+msg);
  }

}
var DummyStore = alt.createStore(DummyStoreProto, 'DummyStore');

// trigger the action
DummyActions.sayHello("Some message");
```